# Get notification from database

Tags: sql, database, notifications, alerts

I have database for example SQL and getting feeds from 3-party into my database (updating everytime it). I need get notification to my application when like examle:

`select * form table Bonus > 50%`

Shall I use windows services and check all database or can I set it in sql and get alert from SQL? I should get notification as soon as possible so to check database every 1 or 5 sec it will be too hard.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on your database. Almost all databases can run triggers when data is changed but the code inside the trigger is usually SQL (which doesn't support opening connections and the like).

Some, like Oracle, allow triggers and they can run Java code as well. Here, you could build a solution inside the database.

But there is a drawback: What happens if the signal can't be sent? Should the whole transaction be rolled back (which would impair other, relatively unrelated services.

So the usual solution is to write code which runs the query in question every hour or so and then sends the signal when the condition is met.

If the query is expensive, then you can mix the two: Run the query only when something has changed (using the trigger) and save the result in a table (like "something happened at $timestamp). In your app, just check whether there was an update since the last signal.